# Get data from Multiple APIs to one ArrayList

Tags: java, android, json, arraylist, android-asynctask

I want to parse JSON data from multiple APIs to one `ArrayList<Object>`
and display it to a `ListView` or `RecycleView`? I've been trying for more than 2 weeks but nothing yet.

I need to make an array list of objects. I need 10 objects every time. The objects' data come from multiple APIs which made my task impossible. i've tried everything I could think of with no results.

Comment: How are you retrieving the JSON data (Retrofit, asynctask etc)?

Comment: I've used Asynctask , Threads, and Volley LIbrary, when i use Async task and Single threads, it crashed duo to multiple HTTp requests i guess (tried ThreadPoolExecuter + Needle library), when i use Volley I can't get data or JsonResponse out of to Add to the ArrayList.

Comment: First I've made a method that makes the http requests and gets back the String, then a method to get each information i need, then i add em all in one single method to add to the ArrayList,(with threads and Async)

Comment: Write more code. Please

Answer (score 0):

If you need to achieve data at one place from several api's simultaneously.

You first need to create a Singleton class or you can create database, where you are storing the results from the api's.

After, all the api call has finished. Just pull the data from singleton class or database and show that in recyclerview.

Put a listener on every api call execution comes as success and increase the counter .And if success count is equals to api calls, show the data on recyclerview.